# Is it possible to support multiple cookie domains in .net core?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

We have an application that is hosted on multiple domains.  Currently we have to deploy to different places with configuration defining the cookie domain.  Is there a way to do this all within one application?

The following code is what we're doing within Startup, ConfigureServices

```
        var cookieDomain = Configuration["CookieDomain"];
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
            options.Cookie.Name = ".SharedCookie";
            options.Cookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

"mydomain.com" works fine.

"mydomain.com,myotherdomain.com" doesn't work at all (no errors, just returns a cookie with the domain "mydomain.com,myotherdomain.com"

calling ConfigureApplicationCookie twice results in the last taking precedence

Comment: Have you tried? Is it giving you some sort of exception?

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for.  Yes - you can't do it through ConfigureApplicationCookie.

Comment: Why not? Does it just not work? Do you get an error? What is happening? Your question needs much more detail about the exact issue you're facing.

Comment: I shall put this in the question as well as you asked so nicely - but it just doesn't work...there's no error, it just doesn't drop a cookie if you try and put more than one domain in.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding. I was thinking you were simply supplying the cookie domain via config, and switching it out per deployment. That should work without issue. However, if you're actually saying that that config value itself is multiple domains, then yeah, that won't work ever.

Comment: In other words, you can only ever set the cookie on a single domain, but you can deploy the same app code to multiple domains and simply use that domain as the cookie domain.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't quite clear.  I have found the answer though, I'll put an answer below for anyone else trying to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved this by implementing a CookieManager and setting the cookie domain for each request, so it is possible to use the same code deployed to the same place, but using different domains.

```
        var cookieDomain = Configuration["CookieDomain"];
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.CookieManager = new CookieManager();
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
            options.Cookie.Name = cookieDomain;
            options.Cookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


public class CookieManager : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ICookieManager
{
    private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ICookieManager ConcreteManager;

    public CookieManager()
    {
        ConcreteManager = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ChunkingCookieManager();
    }

    public string GetRequestCookie(HttpContext context, string key)
    {
        return ConcreteManager.GetRequestCookie(context, key);
    }

    public void AppendResponseCookie(HttpContext context, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
    {
        options.Domain = context.Request.Host.Value;
        ConcreteManager.AppendResponseCookie(context, key, value, options);
    }

    public void DeleteCookie(HttpContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
    {
        options.Domain = context.Request.Host.Value;
        ConcreteManager.DeleteCookie(context, key, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us where you call these functions? I have a similar structured app like yours, I choose the domain in a middleware based on the request's domain. Where should I call these functions? Thank you!

Comment: It worked after I changed context.Request.Host.Value to context.Request.Host.Host